# Flutter - Unable to change button text dynamically

Tags: flutter, dart, dynamic, setstate

I am trying to change the text of a TextButton with setState but for some reason it isn't working.

Initial declaration:

```
 var selectedCountry = '+91';
```

Build function:

//gets called inside build function

```
      Widget _buildPhoneNumberFormWidget() {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          getGlassEffect(
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _showPicker();
              },
              child: Text(
                selectedCountry,
                style: AppTextStyle.textStyleRegular,
              ),
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor:
                    kGlassColor.withOpacity(kAppWidgetColorOpacityFactor),
                minimumSize: Size(
                    SizeConfig.screenWidth * kAppButtonWidthFactor,
                    SizeConfig.screenHeight * kAppButtonHeightFactor),
                maximumSize: Size(
                    SizeConfig.screenWidth * kAppButtonWidthFactor,
                    SizeConfig.screenHeight * kAppButtonHeightFactor),
              ),
            ),
          ),

          SizedBox(
            height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.05,
          ),
          _buildTextFieldWidget(kPhoneNumberHintText, phoneController),
          SizedBox(
            height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.05,
          ),

          ///BUTTON
          getGlassEffect(_sendOtpButton())
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

...
  
_showPicker() {
 showCountryPicker(
  context: context,
  showPhoneCode: true,
    ),   
  onSelect: (Country country) => _setCountryCode(country.phoneCode),
);
}


...
_setCountryCode(countryPhoneCode) {
  setState(() {
    _isCountrySelected = true;
    selectedCountry = countryPhoneCode;
  });
}
```

selectedCountry does not appear anywhere else in the code.

If it helps, I am using the [country_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/country_picker) package.

I debugged and saw that the value of selectedCountry changes correctly, however, it doesn't get updated in the Text.

Comment: From the code you shared here it seems correct - maybe you set a default value for `selectedCountry` in your build function? If possible, please share your whole widget so it's possible to understand it better!

Comment: I found I had a conditional building of _buildPhoneNumberFormWidget(); my bad.